# How to access @propertyWrapper argument in Swift

Tags: swift, property-wrapper

Let's examing following code:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct Argument {
    var wrappedValue: Int?
    var argument: String
}

struct Model {
    @Argument var property: Int?
    @Argument(argument: "bar") var foo: Int? = nil
}

extension Model {
    init(property: Int, argument: String = "hello") {
        _property = Argument(wrappedValue: property, argument: argument)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let model = Model(property: 5)
        print(model)
    }

}
```

Output looks like this:

> Model(_property: propertyWrapper.Argument(wrappedValue: Optional(5),
> argument: "hello"), _foo: propertyWrapper.Argument(wrappedValue: nil,
> argument: "bar"))

So the printing function somehow has access to a property wrapper argument.
However `model.property` is just Int?, the same as `model.foo`. How can I extract arguments like "hello" and "bar" like this?

```
print(model.property.argument) // prints "hello"
print(model.foo.argument) // prints "bar"
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access `foo` and `property` as an `Argument` inside `Model`. Every property wrapped with a property wrapper declares a private property of that property wrapper's type, prefixed with an underscore. You are even assigning to the one for `property` in the initialiser.

So under the hood, `property` is actually declared like:

```
private var _property: Argument
var property: Int? {
    get { _property.wrappedValue }
    set { _property.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

Since it's private, you obviously can't access outside `Model`, but nothing stops you from exposing it :)

```
// in Model
var publicProperty: Argument {
    get { _property }
    // not sure if a setter would be useful...
    // set { _property = newValue }
}
```

Then you can easily print it:

```
print(model.publicProperty.argument)
```

You can even do this by modifying the property wrapper instead, by making the property wrapper be its projected value:

```
// in Argument
var projectedValue: Argument {
    get { self }
    // not sure if a setter would be useful...
    // set { self = newValue }
}

// Usage: prefixing with a dollar sign gets the projected value
print(model.$property.argument)
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew it was somehow possible :)